# C# / MVC Validate model data and call external API based on the results

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have created an WebAPI web app and I would like to validate the data when POST and based on the results to call an external API. 
The data will be saved in the database as it is, apart from the validation results. 
Validation will be done only for calling the external API.
I have created the logic for posting to the external API but I'm not quite sure how it will be the optimal way to validate the data.

My model includes 10 classes like the below Class1 with multiple properties and I've created a controller for each of them. 
The properties can have the true/false values but as strings.

```
public class Class1
{
    public ICollection<Class1Data> Data { get; set; }
}

public class Class1Data
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Prop1{ get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    ..
    public string Prop10 { get; set; }
}
```

WebAPI contoller for POST:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(Class1))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostClass1(Class1 class1)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    db.Class1.Add(class1);
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();

    return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = Class1.Id }, class1);
}
```

I've manage somehow to validate one property and POST to external API but not quite sure how I can do that for all my model classes ( I have around 10, 20 props each ).

```
var notValid = Class1.Data.Where(x => x.Prop1 == "False");

if (notValid != null)
{
    foreach ( var fault in notValid )
    {
        // Call external API using fault.Prop1 / fault.Prop5 / ..
    }    
}
```

How could I achieve this? 
I hope that my question makes any sense to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to use Data Annotations:

Examples:

```
[StringLength(100)]
public string AccountKey { get; set; }

[Required]
[StringLength(100)]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

Or if you need custom validations you can define them as Custom Validation Attributes and use them like below:

```
[Required]
[CountryCode]
[StringLength(3)]
public string CountryCode { get; set; }
```

In this sample `[CountryCode]` is a Custom validation which you can implement like this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Parameter)]
public class CountryCodeAttribute : RegularExpressionAttribute
{
    public CountryCodeAttribute() :
        base("^[A-z]{2,3}([-]{1}[A-z]{2,})?([-]?[A-z]{2})?$")
    {
        ErrorMessage = "Invalid country code.";
    }
}
```

You will need to import this namespace for this kind of validation:

```
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
```

Comment: I was thinking about this approach but have some questions around it : if the validation test fails for one attribute ( even if I throw an error message )  will the data controller still continue to add data to the database? How can I pass to the extenal API (inside the custom validation class) property names (from the model) and values as well.

Comment: I've managed to validate my model inside the model implementing the IValidatableObject interface and it's actually working. Thank you for your advice. Now the only problem that I have is that I'm trying to call an async method ( for calling the extenal API ) inside the Validate model validation method. Not quite sure how I'll be able to solve this, as I have read in the other posts sync <-> async could cause issues.

Comment: @Alex Glad it worked. to call Async within a Sync method you can use a method like this: public static class AsyncHelper
{
 public static T RunSynchronously<T>(Func<Task<T>> asyncCall)
 {
  var threadPoolTask = Task.Run(() =>
  {
   return asyncCall();
  });
  return threadPoolTask.Result;
 } 
}  Then you can use it like this: AsyncHelper.RunSynchronously(() => CallYourAsyncMethodAsync());